# If $f$ is a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function, is $\partial \overline{\partial}\log |f|^2 = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f$ be a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function some simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Let $\partial,\overline{\partial}$ denote the usual Dolbeaut operators.

A book I'm reading seems to claim that $\partial\overline{\partial}\log(|f|^2)$ is always equal to 0. In my attempt to check this, we have:
$$\cdots = \partial\overline{\partial}\log(f\overline{f}) = \partial\overline{\partial}\log f + \partial\overline{\partial}\log\overline{f}$$
Since $\log f$ is holomorphic, the first term on the right is 0, so we wish to show that the second term is also zero. Since $\partial,\overline{\partial}$ anti-commute, we get:
$$\cdots = -\overline{\partial}\partial\log\overline{f}$$
To show that this is $0$, I'm hoping that $\overline{f}$ being antiholomorphic would imply the same of $\log\overline{f}$ will also be antiholomorphic (which would imply $\partial\log\overline{f} = 0$).

Is this true?

Comment: Yes. . Holomorphic and antiholomorphic for composition is  like $1$ and $-1$ for multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those situations where the tangent space viewpoint comes in handy even for such seemingly elementary questions.

Here is the tangent space definition of holomorphicity:

Let $X,Y$ be complex manifolds, and $f : X\rightarrow Y$ be a $C^\infty$ map. Thus, at every $x\in X$, from the standard real theory of tangent spaces we get an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map on real tangent spaces $f_*|_x : T_xX\rightarrow T_{f(x)}Y$. Since $X,Y$ are complex manifolds, both tangent spaces have the natural structures of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. We say that $f$ is holomorphic at $x$ if $f_*|_x$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear. You can find this definition for example in the first chapter of Claire Voisin's excellent book "*Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry I*". Similarly, by taking complex conjugates, we say that $f$ is antiholomorphic at $x$ if $f_*|_x$ is $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear (ie, conjugate-linear). One may check that these definitions agree with the usual notion of holomorphicity or anti-holomorphicity defined in terms of charts.

At this point, the desired result follows from the functoriality of tangent spaces. Indeed, given $C^\infty$ maps between complex manifolds $f : X\rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y\rightarrow Z$ and $x\in X$, we find that $(g\circ f)_*|_x = g_*|_{f(x)}\circ f_*|_x$, so if $f,g$ are both either holomorphic or antiholomorphic, then $g\circ f$ is holomorphic if and only if $f,g$ are both holomorphic or $f,g$ are both antiholomorphic. Similarly, $g\circ f$ is antiholomorphic if and only if exactly one of $f,g$ is holomorphic (and the other is antiholomorphic).

At this point, we can check that indeed $\log\overline{f}$ is antiholomorphic by considering the composite
$$U\stackrel{\overline{f}}{\longrightarrow}f(U)\stackrel{\log}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{C}$$